# can't get rid of vertical dropdown menu padding in firefox

Tags: css, padding

problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qisVn.jpg

The site looks fine on IE, Opera and Chrome, but in Firefox there is a gap between each image in my dropdown menu. I believe the problem is in the CSS.

The same problem occurs in the other browsers when i remove the nave ul li { display: inline-table;}

The CSS:

```
nav ul ul{
display:none;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:28px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
display:block;
}
nav ul{
z-index:2;
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
position:relative;
display:inline-table;
top:-16px;
}
nav ul:after{
clear:both;
}
nav ul li{
display:inline-table;
}
nav ul ul li{
position:relative;
}
nav ul ul ul{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:113px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<nav><ul><li><a onClick="return true" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Fishing','','buttonsandimgs/fishingover.png',1)"><img src="buttonsandimgs/fishing.png" alt="Fishing" name="Fishing" width="113" height="28" border="0" id="Fishing" /></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="fishing.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Seasons','','buttonsandimgs/seasonsdropover.png',1)"><img src="buttonsandimgs/seasonsdrop.png" alt="Seasons" name="Seasons" width="113" height="28" border="0" id="Seasons" /></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Species','','buttonsandimgs/speciesover.png',1)"><img src="buttonsandimgs/species.png" alt="Species" name="Species" width="113" height="28" border="0" id="Species" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="pelagicspecies.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Pelagic','','buttonsandimgs/pelagicover.png',1)"><img src="buttonsandimgs/pelagic.png" alt="Pelagic" name="Pelagic" width="113" height="28" border="0" id="Pelagic" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="reefspecies.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Reef','','buttonsandimgs/reefover.png',1)"><img src="buttonsandimgs/reef.png" alt="Reef" name="Reef" width="113" height="28" border="0" id="Reef" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="estuarysurfspecies.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Estuary/Surf','','buttonsandimgs/estuarysurfover.png',1)"><img src="buttonsandimgs/estuarysurf.png" alt="Estuary/Surf" name="Estuary/Surf" width="113" height="28" border="0" id="Estuary/Surf" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="freshwaterspecies.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Freshwater','','buttonsandimgs/freshwaterover.png',1)"><img src="buttonsandimgs/freshwater.png" alt="Freshwater" name="Freshwater" width="113" height="28" border="0" id="Freshwater" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's the height on the li's

Try changing:

```
nav ul li{
  display:inline-table; 
}
```

To this:

```
nav ul li{
  height: 28px; /* Remove the inline-table and set height same as the images */
}
```

If that doesn't fix it, do you have a live example you can show us?

Hope this helps.